# Use latest apache2 version for php-apache Docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm currently using the `php-apache` docker image for PHP 8.0.14, but the problem is that when I upgrade apache2 inside the docker container, it only gets upgraded to 2.4.51 instead of the latest version 2.4.52.

I can see 2.4.52 has been released in httpd docker images: https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd?tab=tags

How can I upgrade apache2 to the latest version?

Can I use multi-stage build and copy from apache2 image to the php-apache image, or vice-versa? Or split them up in different containers? What is the best practice?

Answer (score 1):

**Upgrade Apache2:**
Might be helpful if you put which php-apache docker image you are using and how you were trying to update it.

**Best Practice:**
It really all depends on your needs, but neither solution is wrong. *In my opinion*, I would go with isolating php and apache in different containers. It makes upgrades like these easier in the future and allows for seperation of concerns.

Comment: Im using the `php:8.0.14-apache` image

Comment: I’m not sure if you are doing this in a dockerfile or through the container, but you should be able to do:
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade